# MVC5 EF 6.1 nested models

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

First I don't know if the technical term nested is correct.  What I am trying to do is in the Shopping view  using:

```
@model test2.Models.Shopping
```

I use the following to add items into the Account table:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Client.Account.BankName)
```

Don't get error when I open the view, however don't get any values for the BankName in the controller.

Would appreciate your suggestions.
Here are the models I am using and Foreign Keys.

[image: Model]

Comment: set breakpoint in view or action and check is there any values in your model?

Comment: Thank you, the value did not show in the model, but it did in the form collection.  This solved my question.